# How to extract a range from a collection in powershell?

Tags: powershell, range, extract

I have a large set of items and I want to extract items from it. I need to skip some items from start and some from end.

The following example is simplified.

I first tried to extract the bounding elements:

```
> ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")[1,-2]
b
d
```

This works as expected.

However when I tried to extract whole range it returns something else than I want (in contrast with Python's `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][1:-1]` which works well).

```
> ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")[1..-2]
b
a
e
d
```

It loops the other way round. How to change the direction of the loop?

I want to get: `b c d`.

Is there a solution without using the real length of the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1..-2 will not count from the first item until two items from the end. Save the array to a variable and specify the upper bound by calculating the array length minus the items from the end.

```
$a = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
$a[1..($a.length-2)]
```

Comment: Is it possible without using the length?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, assigning the array to a variable is a part that I don't like either. You need to know the upper bound first in order to get all items but the last two.

Comment: If objects order doesn't count than maybe with this: 'a','b','c','d','e' | sort | select -skip 1 | sort -desc | select -skip 1

Comment: I wish many times a day for Python-esque slicing in Powershell :)

Comment: @Shay your 'skip-sort solution' from comment does generally work (e.g. when the items will be in arbitrary order).

Answer (score 3):

Since the range operator does not do what you require, a simple pipeline can accomplish the task at hand, though this will likely impact performance for a large collection.

Start with a collection and the number of elements to trim from top and from bottom:

```
$a = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
($fromTop,$fromBottom) = 1, 2
```

Use this...

```
$a | select -skip $fromTop | select -skip $fromBottom -last 1000000
```

...or, if you have PSCX installed, this more concise and elegant sequence:

```
$a | skip -first $fromTop -last $fromBottom
```

Both of those return `b c` without explicitly using the length property. Adjust the two parameters to tailor the output to different ranges.

Answer (score 1):

To just remov the first two ones you can do that :

```
$null,$null,$a = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
```

Comment: How to remove from both sides?